# GitHub Omniauth retrieve user location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, github-api

I'm trying to get GitHub users' location using Omniauth. Everything works fine except the location (I get nil even if mine is set to "Paris"). [The documentation](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema) says it should be "info.location" to retrieve it. Here is my code in my Rails app:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

         def self.from_omniauth(auth)
             where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
               user.provider = auth.provider
               user.uid = auth.uid
               user.email = auth.info.email
               user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
               user.nickname = auth.info.nickname
               user.name = auth.info.name
               user.location = auth.info.location
             end
           end
end
```

Is it possible to retrieve GitHub Users' location?

Comment: I'd use **pry-binding** or **byebug** to stop the execution before the where block inside `. from_omniauth`  and check the `auth` object. The docummentation you are reffering to is from 2014. I'd not rely on that.

Comment: I just check the github-strategy and it seems it's not possible to retrieve user's location: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/github.rb

Comment: I think you can make an extra request to `/users/:username` and get it from there.

Comment: `curl 'https://api.github.com/users/radubogdan?client_id=XXX&client_secret=YYY'` => `{ ..., location: "Cluj-Napoca", ... }`

Comment: It works, thanks guys!